# Creating multiple windows login on a single databae

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am able to create a window login on a database I created. This windows authentication login is based on a windows user that I created earlier, but I don't seem to know how to login into SQL server with the windows authentication login I created. Am I doing things the right way or is there something else that I need to do? Please help me guys. 
I want to have two windows authentication logins into a single database with both logins having different privileges

Comment: You need to log on to windows as either of the users you created and connect to the database using a normal connectoin string, something like this. Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Comment: If they are in the same domain, you should be able to find SQL Management Studio, then Shift+RightClick --> Run as Different User, then enter the credentials you want it to use.

Comment: thanks @Spörri got it working. Sorry for the late appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test your Windows logins with SQL Server Management Studio**

At a very basic level Let's test your logins with SQL Server Management Studio. You need to first log into the Windows machine with the login you created, and then login to SQL Server Management Studio with that same Windows login.

Once you've logged in through Windows, open SQL Server Management Studio and register SQL Server via the connect button Shown in Figure A. Here you register your SQL Server specifically for that login. Next, in Figure B you can connect specifically to SQL Server with the Windows login. The Connect To Server dialog box will automatically have the Windows login information provided that you've selected Windows authentication--but you may need to type the SQL Server name correctly.

**Figure A:** Register SQL Server for your Windows login

[image]

**Figure B:** Test Windows authentication on SQL Server with your Windows login

[image]

p.s. With SQL logins, you're saved the hassle of logging in and out of Windows to test those logins. But I guess you could take a shortcut, hold down the shift key and right-click the SQL Server Studio and select Run as different user--to shortcut the Windows login/logout process.

I've noticed that Run as different user selectively shows up in some places and not in others. For example, in Windows Server 2012's search menu, shift-right clicking SQL Server Studio will not reveal this command, but if I pin Studio to my task bar and shift-right click it's there.

Your question is kind of general (as there are numerous ways to login to SQL Server with Windows authentication)--I hope this explanation is a value to you and is what you needed.